# How to add favicon for Content-Type: application/json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-type, favicon

I am using node.js and implementing an API that returns a response as `Content-Type: application/json` like this:

```js
module.exports={
    api: (req, res) => {
        let data = {"data": [1, 2, 3]};
        res.status(200).json(data);
    }
}
```

But, there is no favicon that can be viewed when trying that API on the browser. I see [another website](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) that can get this done.

[image: api]

How can add a favicon on the Node.js API with `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-favicon.html this?

Comment: you can have a public folder in root with a favicon inside and use `app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));` before the routes. i tested it works

Comment: @cmgchess is it applied on all subpath URL?

Comment: yes by using it on top of all routes it will be applied to all routes. is that what you meant?

Comment: did u get it working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't believe people are suggesting some package for this simple operation.

All browsers request `/favicon.ico` looking for favicon so you have to respond to this request.

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/favicon.ico'))
})

app.get('/api/foo', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ foo: 'bar' })
})
```

[image]

Note: I used duckduckgo's favicon

Comment: This one actually allows you to send a png/gif format favicon if you want to use one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a middleware like the one provided from the [express-favicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-favicon) package that will serve the favicon.ico file before your API route handlers.

e.g

```
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.png'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add your favicon.ico to the root folder of your API and maybe the browser will pick it up. Otherwise there is no way to have a favicon for API's (which are not to be viewed in the browser in the first place, so nobody cares about favicons for APIs...)

Comment: Do you mean in the same folder with `package.json`?

Comment: In summary, the file should be accessible at `http://hostname/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 1):

The request for favicon is a separate request that the browser makes whenever you load a page from your website (can be made from outside the browser too). It is **independent of the other requests** that your server is serving (in your case, the API endpoint serving `application/json` response).

Simplest way to do so would be to handle the request, like any other, in your application:

```js
app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(
         //Path to the favicon file
      );
})
```

However, you would need to set the caching behaviour, in case it is needed.

You can use express' [serve-favicon](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon#readme) package as well which makes it easy to set caching and handles other things as well (such as setting the correct Content-Type etc.).

Answer (score -3):

First, try to put `.ico` file in public folder.

[image]

Second, set the file name.
For example if favicon file name is `file.ico`, then

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/file.ico"/>`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Are you suggesting to insert `<link rel= ... />` in the raw json response? Or in the http headers? If not, where else?